# jQuery Hover on <li>

Tags: jquery, list, hover, href

I have a list of elements like

```
<ol>
<li class="blah">some text <a href=#">test</a></li>
<li class="blah">some text <a href=#">test</a></li>
<li class="blah">some text <a href=#">test</a></li>
<li class="blah">some text <a href=#">test</a></li>
<li class="blah">some text <a href=#">test</a></li>
<li class="blah">some text <a href=#">test</a></li>
<li class="blah">some text <a href=#">test</a></li>
<ol>
```

I want to add a hover element so when the user hovers over the <li> then only that items <a> hovers.

I have this (where hover-enabled is just a color)

```
jQuery('ol li').hover(function () {
    jQuery('ol li.blah a').addClass('hover-enabled');
}, function () {
    jQuery('ol li.blah a').removeClass('hover-enabled');
});
```

It works but ALL of the <a> items hover - not just the individual <li>. Any ideas ?

Comment: What is the problem? explain what you see.

Comment: sorry yeah - the problem is that all of the <a> get the class hover-enabled added not just the individual <li> element ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because that `ol li.blah a` selector is true for all of the list items `a` elements.

This is assuming you want the class applied to the `a` element and not the `li` element.

```
jQuery('ol li').hover(function () {
    jQuery("a", this).addClass('hover-enabled');
}, function () {
    jQuery("a", this).removeClass('hover-enabled');
});
```

If you want the `li` to have the class then use:

```
jQuery('ol li').hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).addClass('hover-enabled');
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('hover-enabled');
});
```

Comment: thanks yeah - i do want to apply it to the "a". but should it be jquery(".blah a", this) ?

Comment: It should not need to reference the `.blah` class. The `this` keyword is the individual `li`, so you just need to pick up the `a` nested within.

Answer (score 1):

it's because in your example you are referencing all of them, you instead want to use this.

```
jQuery('ol li').hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).addClass('hover-enabled');
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('hover-enabled');
});
```

Comment: hi thx - but will that add the hover element ONLY to the <a> element with class blah ? i.e. li.blah a ?

Answer (score 0):

use `this` instead:

```
jQuery('ol li').hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).addClass('hover-enabled');
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('hover-enabled');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has any problem getting this to work you might need to move the code to the end or wrap it in to an document ready function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('ol li').hover(function () {
        jQuery(this).addClass('hover-enabled');
    }, function () {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('hover-enabled');
    });
});
```