# Hover only works on first element of list

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is there a way I can apply a hover effect on a list of items? I have the list below:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li style="list-style-type:none;">
            <div class="listItem">
                <strong>Date: </strong>@Html.ActionLink(item.EventDate.ToLongDateString() + " " + item.EventDate.ToLongTimeString(), "Details", new { id = item.Id }, null)
                <br />
                <strong>Owner: </strong>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.Username)
                <br />
                @Html.ActionLink("Ideas List", "GetEventIdeas", new { controller = "Ideas", id = item.Id })
            </div>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

And I have a jquery as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".listItem").hover(function (e) {
        alert("Hover");
    });
});
```

The alert is only coming up when I hover over the first element on the list. And only for the first time. Why is that and what is the best way to apply hover to all elements in the list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Hover on <li>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533729/jquery-hover-on-li)

Comment: There are no duplicates Koby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me, see this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pPJzeg)

Check your console for any errors/warnings, could be a browser restriction preventing multiple alerts from a page. I tested this in Firefox.

```
<ul>
<li style="list-style-type:none;">
  <div class="listItem">
    <strong>Date: </strong>Date
    <br />
    <strong>Owner: </strong>username
    <br />
  </div>
</li>
  <li style="list-style-type:none;">
  <div class="listItem">
    <strong>Date: </strong>Date
    <br />
    <strong>Owner: </strong>username
    <br />
  </div>
</li>
  <li style="list-style-type:none;">
  <div class="listItem">
    <strong>Date: </strong>Date
    <br />
    <strong>Owner: </strong>username
    <br />
  </div>
</li>
</ul>

.listItem {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
}

$('.listItem').hover(function(e) {
  alert('boo');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work on the IE App but works fine in IE9 and others.

Answer (score 0):

Try using mouseover event instead hover.